# txt file to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make a function that takes a text file, opens it, and returns it as a dictionary.

This is what I have so far, but it does not work and I am not sure why. Any help would be great. Thank You. (I am using python-3.x)

```
def createDictionary(filename):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    textList = [line.rstrip() for line in infile]
    infile.close()
    return dict([x.split(',') for x in textList])
```

Comment: What is your file format, and how do you want to store it in the dictionary? And have you read the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) documentation?

Comment: file format is .txt and it should be stored as strings

Comment: Please show an example of your input and desired output.

Comment: This looks correct, assuming your file contains lines with a single comma separating two items, the first being the key and the second being the value. To help further, we'd need to see input, incorrect output, and expected output.

Comment: What do you expect out of your program when you put what input into it?

Comment: For example, if the file contains lines of Glory|Lotus\n
Hunger|Rose\n
The artists dictionary should contain {‘Glory’:[‘Glory’, ‘Lotus’], ‘Hunger’:[‘Hunger’, ’Rose’]}